# Hide shipping address in PayPal checkout REST API

Tags: paypal, checkout

I am using the current REST API from PayPal on my page. But I am not able to hide the shipping information on PayPal. I don't want to offer the option to my customers to change the address in PayPal.

```
    payment: function(data, actions) {
  return actions.payment.create({
    transactions: [{
      amount: {
        total: '<? print(number_format($got_daten["bestellwert"],2,".","")); ?>',
        currency: 'EUR',
        details: {
            subtotal: '<? print(number_format($got_daten["bestellwert_slim"],2,".","")); ?>',
            shipping: '<? print(number_format($got_daten["orderVersandkosten"],2,".","")); ?>'
        }
      },
    description: 'Krusenhof Etteln - Onlinebestellung',
    custom: 'Bestellung: <? print($got_daten["orderID"]); ?>',
    }],
note_to_payer: 'Rufen Sie uns an bei Fragen! Ihr Krusenhof Etteln'
  });
},
```

How can I add the option to hide (no shipping)?

All the documentations are for the old version and not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the [Payment Experience API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payment-experience/).  Take a look at the [example here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payment-experience/#example).  It shows no_shipping being used.

```
curl -v -X \
  POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payment-experience/web-profiles/ \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
  -d '{
  "name": "ebayProfile",
  "presentation":
  {
    "logo_image": "https://www.paypal.com"
  },
  "input_fields":
  {
    "no_shipping": 1,
    "address_override": 1
  },
  "flow_config":
  {
    "landing_page_type": "billing",
    "bank_txn_pending_url": "https://www.paypal.com"
  }
}'
```